# Can I cap off and ignore red wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I'm replacing a light switch. From the looks of the box and my limited electrical knowledge, it was wired for a 3 way setup (picture below). I can't find any other switch in our house that it's connected to, so my intention is just to cap off the red wire and wire the new switch like a standard single pole switch. Are there any problems with that plan?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Find the switch, before somebody else does and spoils your plans!

The problem with this plan is that someone will find the other switch, flip it to turn the light on or off, and inadvertently disable your now-single-pole light switch in the process.  Either that, or your single pole switch won't work to begin with because the "hidden" 3 way switch is flipped to the wrong position, energizing the capped off red traveller instead of the connected black traveller.  Moral of the story: find all the switches on a circuit before doing anything to it.